# Correct terminology and notation for a set of diffeomorphisms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Being knowingly sloppy because I know I don't know how to be precise (hence the question, and expecting brickbats despite the apology)...

Suppose I have a very ordinary differentiable manifold $M$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with a Cartesian coordinate frame such that $M$ can be foliated by slices $\Sigma$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, indexed by, say, the x-axis (though x is continuous I believe indexed is the right term), such that there is a diffeomorphism $\phi_{x_i, x_i}:\Sigma(x_i)\rightarrow\Sigma(x_j)$ for any $i,j \in$ (some interval) $I$.

1/ What is the terminology and notation for expressing the idea that there is such a set of diffeomorphisms (did I just do it?)

2/ If I excise some region $\mathscr{V_{x_0}}$ from $\Sigma(x_0)$ and require the metric on the $\Sigma(x_i)$ to be fixed (otherwise I would be able to define a new diffeomorphism that generated new metrics via the pushforward/pullback), how do I describe the image of $\mathscr{V_{x_i}}$ throughout $M$...

a) Under $\phi$, and

b) If $\mathscr{V_{x_i}}$ follows some curve $\gamma$ in $M$ that intersects $\Sigma(x_i)$ at $p$ and whose points are not all images of $p$ under $\phi$ (i.e. $\phi$ ceases to be a diffeomorphism as initially defined)

I guess one part of the answer should be about defining diffeomophisms as a continuous function of some variable(s)...

[image]

Comment: Foliation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation

Comment: With respect, that's not an answer that is literally another question. I would like a pedagogical answer that references the specifics given in my question.

Comment: And the opening line of the definition of Foliation at Wikipedia is, AFAICT, wrong. A chart isn't the $U_i$ it's the pair of open sets $U_i$ and the homeomorphisms $\phi_i$; and since the article has "multiple issues", one of which is excessive technicality, I am non the wiser at all.